# Force http on specific folder and maintain https on all others

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, https

I have a site as follows https://domain.com/app/ the site has a folder that houses web services. The path to which is https://domain.com/app/ws/api.php All this works fine, however I want the web service path to be http and not https (remove https from api calls) How can I achieve this? my htaccess is as below

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]


 <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/public_html
   ServerName www.domain.com
   ServerAlias domain.com 
   Redirect permanent / https://domain.com
  <Directory /var/www/domain.com/public_html>
        AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/public_html
   ServerAdmin info@domain.com
   ServerName  www.domain.com
   ServerAlias domain.com
   ErrorLog  /var/www/domain.com/log/error.log
   CustomLog /var/www/domain.com/log/access.log combined

   SSLEngine On
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/domain.com.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/domain.com.key
   SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/domain.com.ca-bundle

<Directory /var/www/domain.com/public_html>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: Do you have VirtualHost setup for both http and https?

Comment: I have amended  the question to include the VirtualHost

Answer (score 1):

```
Redirect permanent / https://example.com
```

in the Virtual Host for HTTP is what is causing HTTPS only connections.

Using Rewrite is more suitable.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(ws)($|/) - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

The first rule will end the rewrite processing, so the dir /ws/.... will not get redirect to HTTPS.

Remove the redirect in your apache virtual host

Comment: Yes I am well aware of that and that is not the problem. The whole site should be on https (hence the Redirect permanent )  but I want a specific folder to be on http while everything else remains as is

Comment: Then you need a separate VirtualHost pointing to that DocumentRoot.

Comment: Just to be sure I got what you are saying...I create a virtual host  for the url pointing to the folder? In my case  https://domain.com/app/ws/

Comment: Come to think of it, using rewrite rules would be more suitable. I updated my answer.